# Formating data for Funnel Report in MySQL Report

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union, unpivot

I looking for a way to create a MySQL report for an Funnel visualization.

So my input is a query asking for a project. Like project-id 123456

```
FROM projects WHERE ID = 123456
```

Result:

```
+---------+--------+-----+----------+------+
| Project | Income | Tax | Payments | Rent |
+---------+--------+-----+----------+------+
|  123456 |   2500 |  50 |      250 |  350 |
+---------+--------+-----+----------+------+
```

For the funnel I need the report like:

```
+------+----------+-------+
| Step |   Name   | Value |
+------+----------+-------+
|    1 | Income   |  2500 |
|    2 | Tax      |    50 |
|    3 | Payments |   250 |
|    4 | Rent     |   350 |
+------+----------+-------+
```

Is there a SQL way to put my query content into new columns (step, Name, value).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` to unpivot your table:

```
select *
fom (
    select 1 step, 'Income' name, Income value from projects where project = 123456
    union all select 2, 'Tax', Tax from projects where project = 123456
    union all select 3, 'Payments', Payments from projects where project = 123456
    union all select 4, 'Rent', Rent from projects where project = 123456
)
order by step
```